# Как сверстать круговой элемент?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, svg

При верстке столкнулся с проблемой,  не знаю, как сверстать данные круги.

[image: Общий блок]
[image: Сама проблема]

Comment: Верстай на svg)

Comment: может помочь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119596/331312

Comment: используйте поиск https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  width: 20%;
}

.item svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.item div {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
}

circle {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 70px;
  fill: none;
}

text {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 80px;
}

.sc {
  stroke: #dfe8ed;
}

.c1 {
  stroke: #30bae7;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  animation: c1 1.5s linear forwards;
}

.c2 {
  stroke: #d74680;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  animation: c2 3s linear forwards;
}

.c3 {
  stroke: #15c7a8;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  animation: c3 4s linear forwards;
}

.c4 {
  stroke: #eb7d4b;
  stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  animation: c4 6s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes c1 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 300 1383;
  }
}

@keyframes c2 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 560 1383;
  }
}

@keyframes c3 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 850 1383;
  }
}

@keyframes c4 {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 0 1383;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1010 1383;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="items">

  <div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="-250 -250 500 500">
      <circle r="180"  class="sc"/>
      <circle r="180"  class="c1"/>
      <text x="-70" y="30"> 15% </text>
    </svg>
    <div>web design</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="-250 -250 500 500">
      <circle r="180"  class="sc"/>
      <circle r="180"  class="c2"/>
      <text x="-70" y="30"> 50% </text>
    </svg>
    <div>html/css</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="-250 -250 500 500">
      <circle r="180"  class="sc"/>
      <circle r="180"  class="c3"/>
      <text x="-70" y="30"> 75% </text>
    </svg>
    <div>graphic design</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <svg viewBox="-250 -250 500 500">
      <circle r="180" class="sc"/>
      <circle r="180" class="c4"/>
      <text x="-70" y="30"> 97% </text>
    </svg>
    <div> ui / ux</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Круги верстаются div'ом, с применением свойства border-radius: 50%;. Высота и ширина блока должны быть одинаковы.
Используя border укажешь толщину и цвет границы, и тип границы круга.
С помощью псевдоклассов after и before задаёшь точно такие же свойства, но отключал border-bottom, left, right. Изменяя ширину и высоту блока (можно прямо в браузере, просмотром кода элемента), подбираешь нужные параметры.
Если толщина линии должна быть меньше, то используя ещё один псевдокласс сменишь цвет границы на текущий и увеличишь толщину линии.